# How can I create a new ticket that's related to the current one?

Tags: youtrack

We have several projects in our YouTrack, one being our email-integrated help desk.

Tickets that come in on the help desk usually cause us to open new tickets in more specific, project-related projects and then linking those new tickets back to the help desk one.

I'm looking for a way to simplify this process, as the path through the UI is currently very long.

Is there a way to command YouTrack to "create a new issue and link it to the currently open one"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a small arrow near the 'Create Issue' button. If you click on it instead of clicking on the button itself you'll get a list of links available on your instance, including 'related to'. If you click on any item in this list, a new issue will be automatically linked to the issue where you were when clicking.

So, in your case you can easily created a related issue right from the screen of the help desk issue.

Comment: Good call. I probably was not specific enough in my question, as I am having this problem while working in an agile board where the UX is different. If you have anything to add in that regard, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Oh yes, Agile board has a different UX... Well, I can suggest you the following workaround: write a workflow action rule (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/Workflow-Rules.html#action-rules) which will create a new issue, linked to the selected card. Then you'll be able to call the action (in a menu or by a command) and then edit the created issue (move it to the right project etc).